# Javascript - proper getAttributeNode on IE6+

Tags: javascript, attributes

I have a regular input box (no onchange attribute).

```
<input type="text" id="bar" name="bar" />
```

For some reason, IE6+ does returns [object], while FF and Chrome returns null.

```
if ((elem.getAttributeNode('onchange')) != null)
  elem.onchange();
```

I did also try as:

```
if (typeof(elem.onchange) !== 'undefined')
  elem.onchange();
```

What would be the proper cross-browser way to check if the element has the attribute?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you wish to know if onchange is a function or not, in which case you can just do

```
if(typeof elem.onchange == 'function')
```